# Separate Page view counter for each page on Blog

Tags: javascript, html, counter, blogger, pageviews

I want a page view counter for my blog. Page view counter must show Post View count of particular Post, not for overall blog.

Example:

```
Post1: View count 10
Post2: View count 6
Post3: View count 18
and so on.
```

I thought a logic that counter will start from 1 and will increase using onload function by 1. But I am unable to implement it.

Because same value I need to pick and onloading the page that value will be increased by 1 and will display in same place.

How can I implement this logic for my blog?

Note: I used many third party hit-counters but either they are un-supportive for HTTPS or counting overall blog count.

Comment: Well you'll need a way of storing the counters.  Do you have one?

Answer (score 0):

If you want specific functions for your counter, you should try to design one with `000webost` or other free PHP/MYSQL hosting sites.